# Glide does not rotate images from camera correctly

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a problem with **Glide**:
If I take a picture from Camera PORTRAIT mode (in my case Pixel XL), the image that is loaded later is rotated by 90° counter clock wise.

Used Glide:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Here is my method to load images:

```
public class BetterRoundedImageView extends RoundedImageView {
    private static final String TAG = BetterRoundedImageView.class.getSimpleName();

    public BetterRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Loads an image given by param url (this sets a default placeholder)
     *
     * @param url The url of the desired image to be loaded
     */
    public void loadImage(final String url) {
        loadImage(url, R.drawable.tracktics_logo);
    }

    /**
     * Loads an image given by param url and a default placeholder while loading
     *
     * @param url              The url of the desired image to be loaded
     * @param placeholderResId the resource Id of the placeholder shown while loading image
     */
    public void loadImage(final String url, @DrawableRes final int placeholderResId) {

        Glide.with(getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .circleCrop()
                .placeholder(placeholderResId)
                .into(BetterRoundedImageView.this);
    }
}
```

This class is extending a `RoundedImageView` from

```
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
```

And it is used like this:

```
playerPhoto.loadImage(data.getProfilePictureUrl(), R.drawable.ic_default_profilepicture);
```

Can anyone help me out here?

---

**Edit:**

Maybe it has something to do how data is stored? In the Activity where I actually take the picture, the image is loaded correctly. But then when I go back to another view, the image is fetched from server (CDN) and cached locally to a Realm db.

Is there something that I miss when storing images on server by sending the base64 string to preserve exif information?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by replacing the library:

`https://github.com/MLSDev/RxImagePicker`

by another Image Picker lib:

`https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper`

and now rotations are properly handled....

Seems like it was not a Glide issue after all!

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue, with this code, the image was rotated 90 degrees

```
 Glide.with(activity).load(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath)).into(imgPicture)
```

Using this code it works as expected

```
Glide.with(activity).asBitmap().load(photoPath).into(imgPicture)
```

Not so much an answer, but maybe a hint to help you on your way.